# Django: How to add object date (or any other field) within a TextField of the same object on Django Template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, ckeditor

info - TextField: The Wednesday six weeks before Easter Sunday – , is a Christian holy day of fasting

Date: February 22, 2023

Both fields are being fetched from database and same object.
I am trying to get the following on my django template:

The Wednesday six weeks before Easter Sunday – ***February 22, 2023***, is a Christian holy day of fasting

Basically injecting date into info field of the same object.,

How should I implement this? I have already tried RichTextUploadingField with:

info - RichTextUploadingField : The Wednesday six weeks before Easter Sunday – {{ obj.date }}, is a Christian holy day of fasting

Template: {{ obj.info|safe }}

However this is not working for me.

Thanks

views:

```
def activity(request, slug):
    template = 'event/activity.html'
    activity = Activity.objects.get(slug=slug)
    date = Date.objects.filter(activity=activity, date__gte=DATE_TODAY)[:1].get()
    context = {
        'activity': activity,
        'date': date,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)

class Date(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Date")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Dates")
        ordering = ['id']

    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("Activity Date"))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

models.py
introduction = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Activity Introduction"))

database:
Wednesday six weeks before Easter Sunday – {{ date.date }}, – is a Christian holy day of fasting,

Template:

{{ activity.introduction|safe }}

Comment: convert your DateTime object into the string using `strftime()` and concatenate it with the rest of the statement will do the thing.

Comment: That wouldn't work because the info is being fetched from database.

info - TextField: The Wednesday six weeks before Easter Sunday – , is a Christian holy day of fasting

I need to concatenate in the middle of a text and I need to somehow define where exactly it should be added.

Comment: Can you Share your code where you're fetching those two diff values separately? you just have to concat.

Comment: I have added it in the original post.

Comment: ok got it. you can concate this but its really weird to do this in middle of statement. Like its static approach which you ll need to change everytime if structure of statement changes. so i think you should display like `Event/Activity` : your statement and then 
`date` : your datetime obj from db separately/ Or you can follow fix structure if you want to concat anyhow

Comment: Yes its somewhat unusual. However I am trying to make it more SEO friendly and easy to read rather than making my sentences unstructured (like adding date at the end or beginning, which is rather straightforward to do). I want to not just do this with this dates but also weekdays, day, year, differential between the current and next date etc. Also I am trying to avoid adding introduction staticly because the words before and after the date will be different for each event, again to make it more SEO friendly. I am using ckeditor so I was hoping there might be a way to put a code

Comment: Where do you return rendered html page in your view with context as parameter ? Also change the date item in the context dictionary in your view to "date":str(date)

Comment: I have added the return line. I cannot date item because date is an object and doing that would not help. May be my question should be how to add django template tags in ckeditor/textfield/charfield etc.